# Magento Core API: Is there way to do configurable products without changing the api?

Tags: api, magento, soap

I am attempting to create configurable products on 1000 different magento sites. (Ok 1000 might not be accurate.. 1 million sounds better).. I'm writing an integration tool that is meant to push products into a magento site.  The application is a SAAS, and we hope to sign up N sites.

Installing plug-ins is not always something the site owners are keen on, so I've avoided all suggestions for altering the "back end".

Where I am stuck now is Configureable products.  I can't seem to find any indication of how to tie configureable products together.

I create the parent product inside the **multicall** like so.

```
     <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
         <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.create</item>
         <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[4]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">configurable</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">40</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">99_nine_555</item>
         </item>
     </item>
```

Then I create the child product

```
     <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
         <item xsi:type="xsd:string">catalog_product.create</item>
         <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[4]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">simple</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">40</item>
           <item xsi:type="xsd:string">nine_5</item>
         </item>
      </item>
```

Then I tried to use ***product_link.assign***, and this didn't work. 
Does anyone know of an out of the box api call to allow someone to create configurable products?

EDIT

---

I know this question seems a repeat of others.  But since none of them had an answer,and most of them are older, I figured perhaps something has changed.  Perhaps there is a way now.  If it was answered, please before you mark this as a repeat, link to the repeat in a comment.

Comment: I didn't think you could do this via API. Documentation isn't very clear either Im afraid. Why not create a product in admin with all options and see if you can retrieve it via API. The response may yield some clues as to if it can be done, if not it may need a custom module. Could you do it with custom options instead of configurable product? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790377/how-to-create-configurable-product-using-magento-api

Comment: I am trying to make an app that can clone a site on a different platform and push products to magento, I can assume one thing: some don't like custom modules.   I'm not sure what custom options are in respect to this. The retrieve via api is a great idea.

Comment: The problem with the previous answer is it assumes the magento is mine.  I don't even have access to the admin screen for some of my clients, much less the box they're sitting on.

Comment: A lot of ERP systems with Magento connectors, need a module to be installed in order to work. I don't have an issue with custom modules, providing they are maintained and work first time. It's pretty straightforward to build a custom API function. The reality here is, that if the standard API doesn't give you ability, what other choice do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The default api does not allow you to do that.

In any case doing this via SOAP is maybe not the best idea. SOAP is know to be slow and if you want to provide this as SAAS the speed matters. If you have 100 products it will be fine, 1000 will work too but any more will take ages.

So SOAP is slow and the Magento API itself is slow.
Magento is slow because it will load the product and call save() including all callbacks, that maybe are not needed to be called.

The best you can do is, as mentioned in the comments, to write your own module, which will take care of the import/update of products.

In addition rather than using SOAP i would recommend using REST for the api.